# Transferring an array to an array in another view (Segue)

Tags: ios, swift, segue

When i want to send data to other view i get this error :

**Value of type 'SecondViewController' has no member 'passingData'**

But it has !

[image]

[image: image2]

SecondViewController :

```
import UIKit
var passingData : [String] = []
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var passingData : [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```